# Joins on same table with MAX()/MIN() and corresponding fileds

Tags: sql, mysql

I made a query for showing max and min value and dates that are corresponding to those MAXs and MINs.

The idea was to show max/min value and the date when the those values occurred in one row for each `ticker`
The code is below.

```
SELECT
    po1.ticker, po1.outermindate as outer_min_date,po1.adj_close as min_adj_close,

    po2.ticker, po2.outermaxdate as outer_max_date,po2.adj_close as max_adj_close
FROM 
    (
        SELECT pm1.ticker, pm1.date as outermindate , pm1.adj_close  FROM pricesmem as pm1
            JOIN 
            (
                SELECT ticker, date as innermindate, min(adj_close)+1-1 as min_close
                FROM pricesmem 
                WHERE date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-10-03" 
                group by ticker
            )
            as pj1
            ON (
                pj1.ticker=pm1.ticker and pj1.min_close=pm1.adj_close
            )

       WHERE pm1.date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-10-03"
    )  as po1
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT pm2.ticker, pm2.date as outermaxdate, pm2.adj_close FROM pricesmem as pm2
        JOIN 
        (
            SELECT ticker, date as innermaxdate, max(adj_close)+1-1 as max_close
            FROM pricesmem 
            WHERE date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-10-03" 
            group by ticker
        )
        as pj1
        ON (
            pj1.ticker=pm2.ticker and pj1.max_close=pm2.adj_close
        )

       WHERE pm2.date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-10-03"
    ) po2
ON po1.ticker=po2.ticker
```

and the results are correct:

```
+--------+----------------+---------------+--------+----------------+---------------+
| ticker | outer_min_date | min_adj_close | ticker | outer_max_date | max_adj_close |
+--------+----------------+---------------+--------+----------------+---------------+
| A      | 2017-01-03     | 46.1764       | A      | 2017-09-19     | 66.0356       |
| AA     | 2017-01-09     | 28.3          | A      | 2017-10-03     | 48.31         |
| etc... |                |               |        |                |               |
+--------+----------------+---------------+--------+----------------+---------------+
```

This way it seems to me that i just join two separate calls to db (not including most inner joins) and i could do same with two calls with any programming lang instead of one sql command.

So is there a better way to make this query?

**EDIT:**
The DB engine is InnoDB, MySQL 5.6.17 .

Comment: What DB engine?